# Equivalence of Django queryset filteration

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've been using the following two interchangeably in a Django project:

`Comments.objects.filter(writer=self.request.user).latest('id')`

and

`Comments.objects.get(writer=self.request.user)`

Are they equivalent in practice? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) don't seem to explicitly address this.

Comment: They both give the same result, but get  is used when there is only one record in the database and where as filter is used to get the queryset. When we use get if the condition fails it will raise <modelname>.DoesNotExist exception where as filter won't raise error instead returns empty Queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not equivalent at all, but this greatly depends on the particular model. We do not know the particulars of your model `Comments`, but if we assume that field writer is not unique:

For the first statement:

> ```
> Comments.objects.filter(writer=self.request.user).latest('id')
> ```

Returns in essence the object with the largest id amongst a queryset of all comments with the particular writer. If one takes a look at the `django.db.connections['default'].queries`, will see that the resulting query is a `SELECT .. ORDER_BY .. LIMIT ..` statement.

For the second statement:

> ```
> Comments.objects.get(writer=self.request.user)
> ```

Returns the particular record fot that writer. In case there are more than one, you get a [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/exceptions/#multipleobjectsreturned) exception. If no object is found, you get a `DoesNotExist` exception. In the event that this would be a unique field or there would be a single object by chance, the resulting query would be a `SELECT .. WHERE` statement which is faster.

Regarding the documentation, if you take a look at the [`Options.get_latest_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.get_latest_by) reference, there is more information regarding the purpose of the `latest` function. Think of it more of a convenience provided by Django. It is nonetheless very important to understand how Django evaluates queries and the resulting SQL, and there are always many ways to achieve the same query so it is a matter of logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would think these are equivalent, or why the docs should address this specifically.

In the case where you only have one matching Comment, yes this will give the same result. But the first version will do it via a more complex query, with an added sort on id.

If you have more than one Comment for that writer - as seems likely - the second version will always give a MultipleObjectsReturned error.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` gives all lines corresponding your filter.

`latest` gives the most recent line (highest id value)

**For example:**

`Comments.objects.filter(writer=self.request.user).latest('id')` gets in first place all `Comments` written by `self.request.user` and then `latest` get the newest from them.

`get` is made to get a unique line, so :

`Comments.objects.get(writer=self.request.user)` will give the comment written by `self.request.user`. There should be only one. If a user can write many comments then you have to use `filter` or maybe `all`. It depends on what you want exactly.

More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/)